# HTTPPOST Attribute not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have a Controller in which two actions are defined.

```
public class ExamlpeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ExampleViewModel { Message = new MessageDisplay { MessageVisible = false, IsGoodMessage = true, Message = String.Empty } });
    }

    // POST:
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Index/{exampleData?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(ExampleViewModel exampleData)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) // If model state is invalid
            // Return view with validation summary
            return View(new ExampleViewModel { Message = new MessageDisplay { MessageVisible = false, IsGoodMessage = true, Message = String.Empty } });
        else // If model state is valid
        {
            // Process further
            bool isGoodMessage = true; // Default

            string message = "success";
            isGoodMessage = true;
            message = "test data";

            // Clear model state if operation successfully completed
            if (isGoodMessage)
                ModelState.Clear();

            return View(new ExampleViewModel { Message = new MessageDisplay { IsGoodMessage = isGoodMessage, MessageVisible = true, Message = message } });
        }
    }
}
```

so, when my view is called then first "Index" action is called but when i post my form it also called first index method.

this code is working fine in old build, new build contains some changes which are not related to this Controller, but it is not working,

when i add  HTTPGET Attribute with first action then it is working fine,
first action called on page load and second action is called on page post.

so, my question is that how Routes are maintained the route table and what is the reason for that condition.

Comment: Display your view code and your rout configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your POST action change `[Route("Index/{exampleData?}")]` to `[Route("Index")]` and it should work. You don't include the POSTed view model as part of the route - think about it, how would it display that posted data in the URL anyway?

Comment: i know that, but {exampleData?} is an optional attribute so it should work when i post page

Comment: i corrected my code according to your solution it is working fine, but my previous code is also working fine, could please explain why HTTPPOST attribute specific method is not calling ,

Comment: is there any specific checklist for actions maintain by MVC Routing before calling any action